# Data Isolation in Salesforce

Tags: data

I have a requirement to isolate customer data from one brand to another. The data will reside on the Sales Cloud. What are the suggested ways of doing this?

Do we have to use Sharing rules on Standard/Custom objects or is there a SFMC's BU-like structure where data residing in one BU is invisible to other BUs.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
Sanchit

Comment: when you say brand you mean product?

Comment: Won't the role hierarchy work for this, e.g. brand 1 is one hierarchy branch, brand 2 is a different hierarchy with sharing set to private and grant access via hierarchies. There will be  a root level that can see both sets of data, e.g. where system admin will be put.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Role Hierarchy seems to be an apt solution, I will explore more on it. I am an Architect on Marketing Cloud with Beginner Level Skills on CRM.